# GET request proxies the correct URL but POST does not React App with Express API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, express

I'm setting up a test react web app to connect to my sql db through an express API. I am testing on my local machine so I run my app on localhost:3000 and I run my server on localhost:4000. I set the proxy in my package.json to "http://localhost:4000". The GET request from my app works perfectly but my post request does not.

//function that makes the POST request in my app:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
        fetch("/api/users",
            {
                method: "POST", 
                body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
            }
        )
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        });
}
```

function to handle this route in my server:

```
router.post('/users', async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        console.log('row is being added...');
        let results = await db.insertUser(req);
        res.json(results);
    } catch(e) {
        res.json();
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }

});
```

db.insertUser function that is called in the previous function:

```
testdb.insertUser = (req) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        pool.query(`INSERT INTO users SET ?`, req.body, (err, results) => {

            if(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }

            return resolve(results);

        });

    })
}
```

This is what appears in the console of my browser after trying to make the POST Request.

```
Response {type: "basic", url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users", redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: true
redirected: false
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
type: "basic"
url: "http://localhost:3000/api/users"
__proto__: Response
}
```

This is the error that I get from my server after attempting the POST

```
(node:85386) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```

I'm not really sure why the POST request is trying to call localhost:3000 and not the proxy localhost:4000 which the GET request successfully calls

UPDATE:

This is the error that I'm now getting in Chrome console

```
Insert.js:37 POST http://localhost:3000/api/users 500 (Internal Server Error)
_callee$ @ Insert.js:37
tryCatch @ runtime.js:62
invoke @ runtime.js:288
prototype.(anonymous function) @ runtime.js:114
asyncGeneratorStep @ asyncToGenerator.js:3
_next @ asyncToGenerator.js:25
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:32
(anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:21
handleSubmit @ Insert.js:50
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:196
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:250
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:265
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:571
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:596
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:695
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:704
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:676
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:844
runExtractedEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:852
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:5030
batchedUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21425
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2247
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5110
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:21482
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:255
interactiveUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21481
interactiveUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2268
dispatchInteractiveEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5086
```

Comment: `router.post('/users')` should be `router.post('/api/users')` no?

Comment: in setting up my server with my api router I use ```app.use('/api', apiRouter);```

Comment: Try status 500, *then* `res.json()`

Comment: FYI: The calls going to localhost:3000 is correct. It doesn't show the proxy port at my local setup either.

Comment: switching the status 500 and res.json() fixes the server error, What am I missing to get the POST to work? I'm now getting the 500 error code but why am I getting an error?